# Collusion not working on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have just reset the computer to factory settings and updated everything and it still doesn't work. It shows the icon on the upper right but it doesn't show the graph. Is anybody else having the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, collusion for chrome no longer works, or is not supported as an extension.  There is another, by the same folks, that does the same thing, just slightly different interface/layout.

You can check it out at:

https://disconnect.me/disconnect